# Encontrar e eliminar caracteres diferentes entre strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst1 = ["carro"]
lst2 = ["carroa", "carrooao"]
```

Como faço para verificar se a palavra em lst1 existe em alguma substring de lst2. Se existir apagar os caracteres excedentes da palavra que possui a substring, tornando a string em lst2, igual ao da lst1. **Sem usar lógicas de comparação de tamanho ou apenas jogar o valor certo nas outras variáveis**. Preciso que o carácter ou substring seja identificado para ser apagado.

Resultado esperado:

```
lst2 = ["carro", "carro"]
```

Comment: Se você quer que o resultado sejam três _strings_ iguais não é mais fácil copiar o conteúdo da primeira _string_?

Comment: Se o conteudo de uma `str4 = "carraao"` o resultado deve ser `"carro"` também?

Comment: @JoséHenriqueLuckmann Sim

Comment: @LINQ Não, a lógica precisa encontrar os caracteres diferentes para que sejam apagados.

Comment: E se eles estiverem fora de ordem? como por exemplo: "acrro"

Comment: @JoséHenriqueLuckmann não se aplica, no meu caso a alteração sempre vai estar no final a direita.

Comment: Totalmente non-sense, é só fazer:  `str2=str3=str1` :-)

Comment: @Sidon acho q não fui claro, alterei o texto do problema pra fazer mais sentido pra vc.

Comment: @GMattos, apenas mais uma dúvida, e se a string não tiver todas as letras, por exemplo : `carraaa`

Comment: Ah tá, agora é uma outra questão, embora continue nonsense. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei meu problema usando duas funções que desenvolvi. A Primeira pegaria uma lista como parâmetro de comparação que seria `modelos` e a palavra que seria comparada como `palavra`. Retornaria o que foi encontrado como anomalia, no caso `"Carroa"`, retornaria `"a"`.

```
def clnw(modelos, palavra):

    for a in modelos:

       palavra = palavra.replace(a, "")

    lx = palavra

   if lx != "":
       return lx 
   else: return ""
```

A função abaixo pegaria o `"a"` como `rst` e a palavra que seria corrigida como `plvr`.

```
def fixw(rst, plvr):
       st = plvr.rfind(rst)
       fn = len(plvr) -1

       plvrl = list(plvr)
       rstl = list(rst)

    while fn >= st:

        del plvrl[fn]

        fn = fn-1
    fix = ''.join(plvrl)

    return fix
```

Retornando `"Carro"`, com essas lógicas dá pra corrigir as strings desde que a anomalia esteja à esquerda, como era meu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi o porque fazer isso, mas de qualquer forma, pode ser feito assim:

```
str1 = "carro"
str2 = "carroa"
str3 = "carrooao"

if ((len(str1) < len(str2)) and (str2[:len(str1)] == str1)):
    str2 = str1;

if ((len(str1) < len(str3)) and (str3[:len(str1)] == str1)):
    str3 = str1;

print str1
print str2
print str3
```

Saida:

> str1 = "carro"
>   str2 = "carro"
>   str3 = "carro"

Comment: Este código não funciona para uma string como `"carraao"`

Comment: A lógica precisa verificar se o carácter é diferente para ser apagado. Desculpe, eu não fui muito claro. No seu caso só se está verificando o tamanho e excluindo a partir do `len()`

Comment: Não pode usar comparação de tamanho. Nonsense, faça `str2=str3=str1`

Answer (score 0):

Já que você não pode simplesmente definir uma variável igual a outra, criei uma função para remover manualmente os excessos, segue um exemplo:

```
def remove_letras(modelo, palavra):
  #passa letra por letra verificando se 
  #existe alguma correspondende e vai removendo 
  #as que não correspondem
  atual = 0
  for letra in modelo:
    palavra = palavra[:atual] + palavra[palavra.find(letra):]
    atual += 1
  #remove os excessos do final
  return  palavra[:atual] 


#TESTES
str1 = "carro"
str2 = "carroa"
str3 = "carrooao"
str4 = "carraao"

str2 = remove_letras(str1, str2)
str3 = remove_letras(str1, str3)
str4 = remove_letras(str1, str4)

print str1
print str2
print str3
print str4
```

Segue o link do teste: [Repl.it](https://repl.it/JPJP/14)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está a minha solução (baseada na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218315/81896) do [José Henrique](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/79084/jos%c3%a9-henrique-luckmann), mas com algumas alterações):

```
def remove_caracteres(modelo, palavra):
    i = 0 # Índice na palavra a ser testada
    n = 0 # Número de caracteres do modelo encontrados na palavra testada
    for letra in modelo:
        while i < len(palavra):
            if letra == palavra[i]:
                i += 1
                n += 1
                break
            i += 1
    if n == len(modelo):
        return modelo
    return palavra
```

A diferença é que essa função é capaz de tratar alguns casos a mais.

**Casos em que os caracteres a mais são removidos:**

- `remove_caracteres("carro", "carroa")`

  > `"carro"`
- `remove_caracteres("carro", "carrooao")`

  > `"carro"`
- `remove_caracteres("carro", "carraao")`

  > `"carro"`

**Casos em que os caracteres a mais *não* são removidos:**

- `remove_caracteres("carro", "carraaa")`

  > `"carraaa"`
- `remove_caracteres("carro", "acrro")`

  > `"acrro"`
- `remove_caracteres("carro", "caro")`

  > `"caro"`
- `remove_caracteres("carro", "carr")`

  > `"carr"`

**Casos extremos:**

- `remove_caracteres("", "carroa")`

  > `""`
- `remove_caracteres("carro", "")`

  > `"carro"`
- `remove_caracteres("", "")`

  > `""`